# Target Specific element in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to apply a method only when a specific element is being target?

Is there a way where i can only pass a method which is being applied to multiple element and only trigger it when a specific element is being target?

see example code below.

aside.component.ts

```
subNavDisplayTitle ="";
subNavDisplay = "";

changeStyle(event) {
    if (this._opened === false) {
      this.subNavDisplay = event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'showSubMenu' : 'sub-nav';
      this.subNavDisplayTitle = event.type == 'mouseover' ? 'showSubMenuTitle' : 'sidebar-title';
    }
  }
```

aside.component.html

```
<ul class="nav">
        <li (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">
            <div  class="sidebar-title" [ngClass]="subNavDisplayTitle">
              <b>Maintenance</b>
            </div>
            <ul [ngClass]="subNavDisplay">
              <li routerLinkActive="visitted"><a routerLink="storageentry">Storage</a></li>
              <li><a>Document type</a></li>
              <li routerLinkActive="visitted"><a routerLink="documentfile">Document file</a></li>
              <li><a>User access</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">
            <div  class="sidebar-title" [ngClass]="subNavDisplayTitle">
              <b>Maintenance</b>
            </div>
            <ul [ngClass]="subNavDisplay">
              <li routerLinkActive="visitted"><a routerLink="uploadfile">File upload</a></li>
              <li routerLinkActive="visitted"><a routerLink="borrowdocument">Borrow document</a></li>
              <li><a>Document transfer</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li (mouseover)="changeStyle($event)" (mouseout)="changeStyle($event)">
            <div  class="sidebar-title" [ngClass]="subNavDisplayTitle">
              <b>Maintenance</b>
            </div>
            <ul [ngClass]="subNavDisplay">
              <li routerLinkActive="visitted"><a routerLink="documentlist">Document list</a></li>
              <li routerLinkActive="visitted"><a routerLink="documentlocation">Document location</a></li>
              <li><a>Document Transaction</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Here's what happen when i hover the sidebar nav
[See Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foONj.png)

[the CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG3uv.png)

Comment: And what do you expect?

Comment: i want to display the subnav when a specific list is hover.. but it shows all list item was display when i hover a specific list.

Comment: What I understood is, you want to show the `<ul>` only when the particular `<li>` is hovered. Is that correct ?

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want to happen.

Comment: In that case, you might have to show what classes/styles are you applying on `mousein and mouseout`

Comment: on mouseover and mouseout i put a method there which holds my classes (subNavDisplayTitle and subNavDisplay) and fire every time li is hover. and i want to display this method when only a particular is being hover.

Comment: I got the class name from your code, but what exactly is the css for these class

Comment: ill attached the css.

Comment: here's the css https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG3uv.png

Comment: it's a **png**...

Comment: Based on your classes, it seems you are assigning the classes once, thus making the `display:inline-block` but never removing those classes on `mouseout`.

Comment: yes, i only used ngStyle on it that display: none when my sidebar is being dock. here's the code    <div  class="sidebar-title" [ngClass]="subNavDisplayTitle" [ngStyle]="{'display': _opened === false ? 'none' : 'inline-block'}">